# How get data directly from a google spreadsheet?

Tags: android, google-api, google-sheets

I need my android application to connect ALWAYS to the same google spreadsheet to get cells data (that i will change in the future every day so the application can get updated data without use a server).

In documentation https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=it#ListFeeds it's showed how to authenticate etc but what i need would be to connect to a public spreadsheet using the straight link like:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=xxx....

Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible!! I coded a js lib for this but not for android(Didnt check). [Gsheet2json](http://rumal.github.com/Gsheet2json/) May be the library or the code might help you to port it to android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is possible, some example can be the code of James Moore http://blog.restphone.com/2011/05/very-simple-google-spreadsheet-code.html

Remember you need to add manually in spreadsheet "File->Publish to the Web"

```
package com.banshee;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
    import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CustomElementCollection;
    import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
    import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
    import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

    public class SpreadsheetSucker {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("com.banshee");
        try {
          // Notice that the url ends
          // with default/public/values.
          // That wasn't obvious (at least to me)
          // from the documentation.
          String urlString = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AsaDhyyXNaFSdDJ2VUxtVGVWN1Yza1loU1RPVVU3OFE/default/public/values";

          // turn the string into a URL
          URL url = new URL(urlString);

          // You could substitute a cell feed here in place of
          // the list feed
          ListFeed feed = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class);

          for (ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
            CustomElementCollection elements = entry.getCustomElements();
            String name = elements.getValue("name");
            System.out.println(name);
            String number = elements.getValue("Number");
            System.out.println(number);
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me !!! but we must remember that we have to add guava.jar (guava-18.jar in my proj), in manifest file add permissions, and finally, set threadpolicy to PermitAll() .  thats all :)

Comment: No longer supported as Google has mandated OAuth2.0 for accessing data from Sheets. There is still a workaround by accessing the Sheets data as JSON and parsing it at your app's end.

Access JSON using this URL: https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=<sheets-key>

E.g.: https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1tJ64Y8hje0ui4ap9U33h3KWwpxT_-JuVMSZzxD2Er8k