# Android - Unable to merge dex with Google Data Library

Tags: android, google-sheets-api, gdata, android-multidex

I have this android project that worked well. My idea was that I was going to use an already-existing Google Sheets as my database for the app. I searched and searched until I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642932/how-get-data-directly-from-a-google-spreadsheet). So I added

1. gdata-client-1.0.jar
2. gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
3. gdata-core-1.0.jar
4. gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
5. gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
6. guava-11.0.2.jar

Then the error came up:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

So I tried using

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

which worked well (successful gradle) until I ran the project.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
```

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\AndroidStudioProjects\Corporate Outcome Request System (CORS)\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava-jdk5\17.0\463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36\guava-jdk5-17.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))

This is my build.gradle now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.YearZero.CORS"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev496-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

There were also instances where I got **transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug** and **transformClassesWithDexlistForDebug**
:P

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have found regarding your type of error. I am giving examples similar to your case.

**Solution**

Try place the following `exclude group: 'com.google.guava'` in either the com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0 or com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev496-1.23.0 and see what happens.

**In some cases:**

1. There could be some conflict behind your dependencies and gradle may not know how to resolve them. For instance if your app's `build.gradle` contain different versions of the same dependency e.g one dependency uses `play-services:11.6.0` and another `play-services:11.6.1` gradle may not know how to merge them. Another example could be you have `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0` but your design
   library may be using an older version e.g
   `'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'`
2. In some cases if you are using an emulator/device that contains an older version of your app  and you change your dependencies on your app's `build.gradle` that create the conflict mentioned in (step 1). The simple solution here is to uninstall on your device and reinstall

Comment: Thanks but there are no duplicate dependencies in my build.gradle file and removing 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' doesn't help and removing 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0' returns many errors. I tried uninstalling the app on my device and rerunning it still gives the same error. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Hey iBlueDust,  I was giving an example when I mentioned the disparate versions on `appcompat` and `design` libraries. I was not pointing directly to your code. That seems fine.

Comment: Looking at your error carefully its complaining that there is a duplicate `guava` dependency that `:com/google/common/annotations/` already has. So you will have to manually exclude it from gradle or delete the .jar so as to alleviate the dependency mismatch

Comment: Try place the following ` exclude group: 'com.google.guava'` in either the `com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0` or `com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev496-1.23.0` and see what happens

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to this. I just had to take a long break from its frustrations. Deleting guava and adding exclude worked. Thanks very much martinomburajr!

Comment: Hey @iBlueDust, sorry about the frustrations, I know gradle can sometimes be a pain. glad I could help out. I have updated my answer to include what helped. If you find that my solution did solve your problem, please feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once :-

```
android {
      defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        }
   }
```

may be it will help you..